# Extract tgz file in memory and access files in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharpziplib

I have a service that downloads a `*.tgz` file from a remote endpoint. I use `SharpZipLib` to extract and write the content of that compressed archive to disk. But now I want to prevent writing the files to disk (*because that process doesn't have write permissions on that disk*) and keep them in memory.

How can I access the decompressed files from memory? (*Let's assume the archive holds simple text files*)

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public void Decompress(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        Stream inStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);

        TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
        tarArchive.ExtractContents(@".");
        tarArchive.Close();

        gzipStream.Close();
        inStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Tar/TarArchive.cs#L549) and [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Tar/TarArchive.cs#L582) out.

Turns out, `ExtractContents()` works by iterating over `TarInputStream`. When you create your `TarArchive` like this:

```
TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
```

it actually wraps the stream you're passing into a `TarInputStream`. Thus, if you want more fine-grained control over how you extract files, you must use `TarInputStream` directly.

See, if you can iterate over files, directories and actual file contents like this:

```
Stream inStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);

using (var tarInputStream = new TarInputStream(gzipStream))
{
    TarEntry entry;
    while ((entry = tarInputStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        var fileName = entry.Name;
        using (var fileContents = new MemoryStream())
        {
            tarInputStream.CopyEntryContents(fileContents);
            
            // use entry, fileName or fileContents here
        }
    }
}
```